# Слияние файлов с отсортированными строками в Delphi

Tags: delphi, сортировка

У меня есть большой файл который нужно отсортировать. 
Я поделил его на блоки, отсортировал и записал в различных файлах в порядке 1-n . Последний файл наименьший. Как мне теперь произвести слияние этих файлов в один если изначально мне не известно их количество ? Как мне обьединить их в один ? И при объединении итоговый файл станет полностью отсортированным ?

Comment: 1. Читать один-за-другим. 2. Открыть хандл на новый файл, и писать все файлы в него не закрывая хандл. Закрыть после записи всех кусков. 3. Если куски расположены несортировано - итог - несортированый файл.

Comment: Извините , небольшое уточнение . Простите что забыл . В файлах находится разное количество строк так как они создаются одинакового размера но размер строк в них разный .

Comment: Подпором я бы сформулировал так

Comment: Подпором я бы сформулировал так. Имея n  файлов с разным кол-вом строк   как пробежать по ним до конца  читая строки . Парметр n заранее не известен , а определяемся в процессе работы программы .

Comment: А что в прошлой ветке?

Comment: открываете один выходной файл, и все входные.  читаете по строке из каждого входного. Находите среди  этих N строк минимальную, и пишите в выход. Читаете из этого же файла новую строку. и зацикливаете это чтение/минимум до конца всех файлов. То есть за итерацию цикла у вас будет одно чтение из одного файла, поиск минимума, и одна запись. Когда всех входные достигнут oef, то завершаете работу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе основной программы сохраняете файлы в одну папку, скажем "\Results".
Алгоритм программы обработки:
1. Создать `Files: TStringList`
2. Через `FindFirst/FindNext` ищем все файлы в этой папке "\Results". При нахождении каждого файла выполняете следующие действия:
2.1. Открыть найденный файл через `Assign(h, ""); Reset(h);`
2.2. Считать одну строку в переменную `S`.
2.3. Добавить в `Files` строку `S` с идентификатором файла `h` в качестве объекта `Files.AddObject()`.
3. Создать выходной файл `Assign(Out, ""); Rewrite(Out);`
4. Отсортировать `Files`
5. Записать в Out первую строку из `Files.Strings[0]`
6. Проверить файл, идентификатор которого записан в `Files.Objexts[0]`, на `EOF`
6.1 Если не конец, то считать новую строку из файла и занести в `Files.Strings[0]`
6.2 Если конец файла, то закрыть файл, удалить объект и строку из `Files`
7. Если `Files` пуст, то закончили, иначе Перейти в п.4